# SQL How to group by two different columns that contain the same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to group the following data together.

 Note that identical data can be in different columns and they can also be in the same column.

```
| Id | Mobile | Home   |
| 1  | NULL   | 626... | 
| 2  | 626... | NULL   |
| 3  | 405... | NULL   |
| 4  | NULL   | 405... |
| 5  | 626... | 405... |
| 6  | 405... | 626... |
```

such that it produce this result

```
| GroupId | Id |
| 1       | 1  |
| 1       | 2  |
| 1       | 5  |
| 1       | 6  |

| 2       | 3  |
| 2       | 4  | 
| 2       | 5  | 
| 2       | 6  |
```

GroupId can be a random generated ID eg. NEWID(), it is used to identify "duplicates" across different columns

 Null values are ignored.

Comment: What is GroupId? Explain the logic used to get that output

Comment: I think you have to be clearer about what you are trying to do here. I kind of get what you want to do after looking at it for too long, but you need to give a better data example.

Comment: What if neither value is `NULL`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated the question a bit, hopefully that's a bit more clear

Comment: @wavery the idea is pretty much to group all the duplicate phone numbers together regardless of which column it's in

Comment: Apologies as the question is not clear to its intent. What I'm trying to do is group rows by their data, and the data can span multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  of two [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) of the base table. In these projections, rows containing `NULL` in the `MOBILE` and `HOME` columns, respectively, are excluded. Then apply the `DENSE_RANK` function to the result set.

```
WITH
  t AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      VALUES(1, NULL, 626456),
      (2, 626456, NULL),
      (3, 405123, NULL),
      (4, NULL, 405123),
      (5, 626456, 405123),
      (6, 405123, 626456)
    ) AS t (id, mobile, home)
  ),
  u AS (
    SELECT id, mobile AS dr FROM t WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, home FROM t WHERE home IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY dr DESC) AS GroupId, Id
FROM u
ORDER BY GroupId, Id;
```

**Output:**

```
+---------+----+
| GroupId | Id |
+---------+----+
|       1 |  1 |
|       1 |  2 |
|       1 |  5 |
|       1 |  6 |
|       2 |  3 |
|       2 |  4 |
|       2 |  5 |
|       2 |  6 |
+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need the `COALESCE` to return the non-null value from the `Mobile` , `Home` values and based on the result you can grouping the text and create the `GroupId`.

So you can apply `COALESCE(Mobile, Home)` and `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY`.

Please find the demo with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, Mobile INT, Home INT);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, Mobile, Home) VALUES
(1, NULL, 626456),
(2, 626456, NULL),
(3, 405123, NULL),
(4, NULL, 405123);

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COALESCE(Mobile, Home)) AS GroupId,
       Id
FROM @TestTable
ORDER BY Id
```

Here I used `ORDER BY` based on the `COALESCE` result, you can change it to according your business need.

[**Demo on db <> fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75b9f4a62e58fe057fcf03e5d5072ec9)

Comment: `COALESCE()` does not "concatenate" values.  I realize that English may not be your native language, but your statement is quite misleading.

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks for taking the time to tackle this problem, I updated the fiddle two more rows of data that would yield an undesired result

Comment: @AllenChen Can you please share the updated fiddle link. The fiddle link will change for every execution,

Comment: @AllenChen if you have more sample data that is vital to understand the question then add them and the expected output to your question

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as I find it difficult to explain what I was attempting to accomplish. If anyone comes across this please see if this is a potential solution

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    VALUES(1, NULL, 626456),
    (2, 626456, NULL),
    (3, 405123, NULL),
    (4, NULL, 405123),
    (5, 626456, 405123),
    (6, 405123, 626456)) AS tbl (id, mobile, home)
),
PivotCte AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT pvt.value
  FROM    CTE
  CROSS   APPLY (VALUES('mobile', mobile), ('home', home)) AS pvt (phone, value)
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.value) as gid, c.id
FROM   CTE c
INNER JOIN PivotCte p ON c.mobile = p.value OR c.home = p.value
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=55e00cb09f73c84f770e626ba2e6671b)